# How to remove blank page after title page in LaTex?

Tags: blank-page

I'm trying to use LaTeX to create a document but a random page is created after the front page and I'm not sure of the best way to remove it. As you can see in the document class I've added `openany` which should make the document one-sided and yet this page is still being randomly added. I've added the code below and an image of what's produced. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{book}
\RequirePackage{fullpage}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize}
\RequirePackage{t1enc}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\RequirePackage{array}



\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\makeatletter
% No extra space between chapter number and chapter header lines:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 20}{\vskip 0} {}{}
% Reduce extra space between chapter header and section header lines by 50%:
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{} % for unnumbered chapters
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            
            \Huge
            \textbf{Engineering + Engineering = Engineering}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \LARGE
            Design of of something something something
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{university.jpg}
            \centering
            
            
            
            
            \textbf{John Smith}
            
            \vfill
            
            A thesis submitted to the School of Engineering\\ 
            at the University of Hull for the degree of\\ 
            MASTER OF ENGINEERING    
            
            
            \vspace{0.8cm}
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            \Large
            School of  Engineering\\
            University of Hull\\
            United Kingdom\\
            October 2023
            
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \newpage
    \frontmatter
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \centering
    
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \Huge
    
    \normalsize
    \par
    \emph{“Some Sort of Inspirational Quote.” }
    John Smith
    \vspace*{\fill}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\frontmatter` is the cause behind this as it inserts a `\cleardoublepage`. While `\newpage` and `\clearpage` are gobbled if used successively, `\cleardoublepage` does more than just clear a page or possibly more. In order to succeed in possibly clearing a blank page as well, it inserts an `\hbox{}` on a page (which prints nothing) and then issues another `\newpage`, otherwise it may be gobbled. Here's the actual definition (from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

So, here's your sequence of instructions:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  % <title stuff>
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\frontmatter
```

The `titlepage` is constructed on page 1. Then you insert a `\newpage`, putting you on page 2. Issuing `\frontmatter` on page 2, leaves `\cleardoublepage` to call:

```
\clearpage % ...this is gobbled, since the it follows from a \newpage
\if@twoside % ...this is true within book
  \ifodd\c@page % ...this is false, so
  \else %         ...follow this branch
    \hbox{}%      ...insert something that doesn't print anything
    \newpage%     ...issue a (legal) \newpage
    \if@twocolumn%...this is false...
      \hbox{}%
      \newpage%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi}
```

You can remove the blank page using [`atbegshi`](//ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi)'s `\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}`:

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\begin{titlepage}
  % <title stuff>
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}% Discard next blank page

\frontmatter
```

or just do whatever `\frontmatter` does manually. Here's `\frontmatter`'s definition from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
```

Since you're changing the page numbering anyway, just use

```
\begin{titlepage}
  % <title stuff>
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\csname @mainmatterfalse\endcsname
```

(which avoids using a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)).